# Amazon CloudFront with Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-cloudfront

I use route 53 as my dns serever
then I have a A record in my route 53 records called
 `image.mysite.com.    A    111.222.333.444`

then I want to use CloudFront as my cdn to caching images
then I added new Distributions and removed the A record
added cname:

```
image.mysite.com.    CNAME    d23456.cloudfront.net
```

but when I visit my website image.mysite.com it show

```
Sorry, invalid request
```

and when i trying to visit d23456.cloudfront.net directly it displayed:

```
ERROR

Failed to contact the origin.
```

how can I successfully use CloudFront as image.mysite.com CDN and use route 53 as dns server?

Comment: What DNS name did you add for the custom origin in CloudFront?

Comment: I type image.mysite.com in Cloudfront origin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment it seems that you point CloudFront to the origin server `images.mysite.com` which actually points back to CloudFront so CloudFront doesn't know how to access your site.

Create another DNS record (e.g. `origin.mysite.com. IN A 111.222.333.444`) and point CloudFront to it. After that CloudFront would respond to requests to `images.mysite.com` with data from `origin.mysite.com`.

Comment: do you mean add DNS record [origin.mysite.com. A 111.222.333.444] and [image.mysite.com. CNAME d23456.cloudfront.net] then turn CloudFront Origin to origin.mysite.com?but how cloudfront cache images in image.mysite.com?

Comment: Yes. You can also use any already existing DNS name. It just can't be the same DNS name that you use point to CloudFront.

Comment: but I want CloudFront cache the images at server image.mysite.com

Comment: The official DNS name for your site will still be `image.mysite.com`. `origin.mysite.com` would only be used by CloudFront itself. Otherwise CloudFront can't know where your origin server is because `image.mysite.com` points to Amazon servers and not yours.

Comment: also one more problem,if i type [image.mysite.com. A 111.222.333.444] then visit image.mysite.com will match the vhost in my server,does your method works fine?I mean can display the webpage successfully

Comment: You would need to update your vhost configuration because `image.mysite.com` would not point to your vhost anymore.

Comment: so how can I use CloudFront as CDN but keep "image" as mysite.com subdomain and server vhost?

Comment: That is not possible then because the DNS name must point to CloudFront or your vhost, but not both at the same time. Either your vhost or the CloudFront distribution will need to use a different DNS name.

Comment: so cloudfront cannot so something like cloudflare?